# How do I get OpenSSL style salted MD5 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, openssl, md5, salt, crypt

I'm talking about this:

```
$ openssl passwd -1 -salt thesalt thepassword
$1$thesalt$HAWpBmvUCutuyTS4JwevI.
```

In PHP it would look like this:

```
crypt('thepassword', ('$1$'.'thesalt')); # this gives the same output as above
```

I'm trying to achieve the same format in Ruby 1.9. I've been told Ruby's String#crypt will do this but it does not. I've looked everywhere for an answer, but I've come across nothing.

If it helps anything, I'm trying to do this on Windows XP.
Ruby version: ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]

Just to keep away the comments telling me to use something other than MD5 or whatever else, I would if I could. This choice isn't up to me.

Thanks.

Edit: I want to do this without shelling out to openssl because that would be too slow for what I need.

Comment: If anyone is interested I did find a Ruby gem called Crypt3 that does what I want but unfortunately it's too slow. I've optimized it a bit but that didn't help much. I may rewrite it in C and see what that gets me.

Comment: If you're going to use it for password authentication, slow may be exactly what you want. The faster it is the easier it will be to brute force attack.

Comment: Computationally slow, yes. Not slow in implementation. That's not what I'm using it for anyway. Thank you for your reply though.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you could call the `openssl` executable using backticks:

```
password = "thepassword"
salt = "thesalt"
hashed = `openssl passwd -1 -salt #{salt} #{password}`

puts hashed  # => $1$thesalt$HAWpBmvUCutuyTS4JwevI.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want to avoid calling openssl because doing so in batch jobs is very very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Darn. I was hoping for the same thing.

see also [Generate openssl password with Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480812/generate-openssl-password-with-ruby) for the reason why it is not in ruby.