# Generate openssl password with Ruby

Tags: ruby, openssl

I'd like to use the ruby openssl library to generate the same thing as this openssl command:

```
$ openssl passwd -1 mypassword
```

Right now, in my code, I'm doing this:

```
mypass = `openssl passwd -1 mypassword`
```

... this works, but it seems silly.  I feel like you should be able to use OpenSSL::Digest to achieve the same result.  However, I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`openssl passwd -1` implements [UNIX crypt(3) algorithm](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt). The implementation (md5crypt) resides in [`apps/passwd.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL097/OpenSSL097-105/openssl/apps/passwd.c). As a result, the implementation code is not a OpenSSL library function. As the function comment says:

> MD5-based password algorithm (should probably be available as a
>   library function; then the static buffer would not be acceptable).

So you will not find it in OpenSSL::Digest.

However, you may find other libraries useful, such as [unix-crypt](https://github.com/mogest/unix-crypt).

Answer (score 1):

This is compatible with `openssl passwd -1`

```rb
require 'openssl'

module CryptMD5
  refine String do
    def crypt_md5 salt = OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(6)
      crypt ['$1$', salt].pack('a3m0').tr(?+, ?.).delete(?=)
    end
  end
end

using CryptMD5
pass = '$1$i7VbAY.b$uy5kgtLn8m2daMxOBEz6p.'
salt = pass[3..10].tr(?., ?+).unpack1 'm0'

puts pass == 'secret'.crypt_md5(salt) # => true
puts pass == 'secret'.crypt_md5(salt + 'ignored extra') # => true
puts 'secret'.crypt_md5 # => $1$bMylNdtr$/fxt7r7gzdossTabWD/xT/
puts 'secret'.crypt_md5 # => $1$y6O7OsY7$bDl3yEKJXM0lhg3DYye6Z1

pass = `openssl passwd -1 secret`.chomp
salt =  pass[3..10].tr(?., ?+).unpack1 'm0'
puts pass == 'secret'.crypt_md5(salt) # => true
```

Calling `String#crypt` with a string usually only uses the first two characters as salt, but if prefixed with `$1$` it will use the next 6 bytes / 8 characters as a salt with a modified base64 alphabet (swapping `+` and `.`). Any more bytes / chars are just truncated.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.hexdigest(mypassword)
```

Comment: If my password is 'secret', the openssl command produces: $1$i7VbAY.b$uy5kgtLn8m2daMxOBEz6p. Your Ruby openssl digest command produces: ebe2294ecd0e0f08eab7690d2a6ee69